# Ошибка Базы данных sqlite3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

При попытки добавление в базу выходит ошибка о том что она якобы  закрыта.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/dmozo/Desktop/Tester Creater/2.py", line 86, in save
    conn.commit()

sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Код:

```
o=valueChosen.get()
n=n1.get()
t=t1.get()
y=y1.get()
h=h1.get()
va=vari.get()
t_2=(n,t,y,h,str(va))
conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')
conn.execute("INSERT INTO Test_"+o+" (vopros,otv1,otv2,otv3,pravotv)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", t_2)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Как подобную ошибку исправить?

Comment: А еще `sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')` в коде встречаются?

Comment: Встречался с подобным при попытке использовать `sqlite` в многопоточных приложениях.  Он с ними не до конца дружит и требует специальной настройки.

Comment: Да встречается как можно эту ошибку исправить

Comment: Убедиться, что база не открывается еще раз если была открыта. Можно написать враппер, который либо откроет, либо переиспользует коннект и закроет только тогда, когда количество close() будет исчерпает количество открытых.

Comment: Если бы connect должен быть close. Всегда, похоже выше вашего кода вы делали connect, но не завершили close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте на каждый `connect` вызывать `close`, добавьте конструкцию `try...finally`, где у вас работа с базой, чтобы всегда `close` вызывался, например:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')
try:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Test_"+o+" (vopros,otv1,otv2,otv3,pravotv)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", t_2)
    conn.commit()

finally:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: ток не `final`, a `finally`

Comment: @AndrioSkur, вы правы :)

Comment: @Дмитрий, боюсь ничем больше помочь не смогу :(

Comment: Вместо try/finally можно with-конструкцию использовать (или с самим соединением или с курсором)

Comment: @jfs, with вроде бы `commit` автоматически вызывает, а не `close`? Сужу по описанию в https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager

Comment: `with closing(conn):`